# removeFromSuperview for some reason replaces object with UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have been through every single thing allocated in my code and given it a tag of -1, except from the Icons, which use up the tag system. So here's my code:

```
NSLog(@" 1: %@", (Icon *)[self viewWithTag:index]);
    Icon *icon = (Icon *)[self viewWithTag:index];
    CGRect frame = icon.frame;
    [icon removeFromSuperview];
    icon = nil;

    Icon *icon2 = [[Icon alloc] init];
    [icon2 makeIconStandardWithTag:(int)index];
    icon2.frame = frame;
    [self addSubview:icon2];

    NSLog(@" 2: %@", (Icon *)[self viewWithTag:index]);
```

NSLog 1 returns the object to be an icon. NSLog 2 returns the object to be a UIImageView, despite me searching my code thoroughly for every UIImageView and giving it a -1 tag. Through moving NSLog 2 around, i've discovered that the line `[icon removeFromSuperview];` is the problem here. If that line isn't included, it doesn't happen. But obviously i need to remove it from superview and `.alpha = 0`is too much of a patch-over fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What value are you using for the tag? Sometimes I have troubles if I use a value that's too low (I assume because `UIKit` is using that tag value).

Try setting `index` to some random large number.

Also, why not just use an instance variable to refer to the Icon? Then you won't have to mess around with identifying the icon by its tag.

Comment: It only ever happens on index 0.

Comment: Well that's probably your problem. There shouldn't be any reason that you must use a tag value of 0. Can you try using larger values.

Comment: I have a bunch of objects to load in from an array, and that starts at 0. I don't really want to have to change it to arrayindex+1, and then change it back again when the user presses it to figure out which one to open.

Comment: Well, hey. If it's doesn't work it doesn't work, so you might have to deal with the pain of adding 500 to your array indicies to get the tag value. If bothers you that much, you can write a simple -(int)tagForIcon: method to hide the ugly transformation. : )  And you can always just keep a reference to the icons, in an NSMutableArray, say, so you don't have to screw around with tags.